# How do I acquire new powers?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What I refer to when I mention "powers", is the abilities I am able to get in the game. You can find it by going to magic in the menu then to powers. From the beginning of my playing the game up to probably about the second to the last time I've played it, I've only had one power (Battle Cry). I want to know how to get more powers. I was able to get a power that enabled me to turn into a werewolf, but that came from one of the quests. Will I have to wait more while doing the quests to get a new power, or is there some other way? Do I have to use the enchantment tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an extensive list of [powers](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Powers) and how to get them on the UESP site.

Most of these powers are racial bonuses (including Battle Cry, which means you were playing as a Nord), which means your selection of race determines your "starting power."

However, many are also rewards from particular quests. You can find links to the quests required for each power on the UESP page.

For instance, there is a set of powers available to [high-ranking members](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Darkness_Returns) of the Thieves' Guild, and there is a particular power only available for completing an [optional objective](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bound_Until_Death) during the Assassin's Guild quest line.

Certain powers are granted by activating a [Standing Stone](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stone) - do note that you can only have one stone active at a time, and not every standing stone grants a power.  Some give only passive bonuses.

Additionally, certain "conditions" - notably being a werewolf or vampire - also confer powers as part of their effects.

Comment: Also summon spectral assassin

Comment: @OutlawLemur, yes - that's the reward for the assassin's guild quest line (there's a link in my answer that takes you directly to that quest's page on the UESP)

Comment: Oh must have missed that sorry